# Mplayer no video or audio on Intel HD 530 in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, intel-graphics, mplayer, gpu-driver

I have an Intel i3-6100 processor running Xubuntu 16.04.  I'd like to get Mplayer working.

I have tried some workarounds.  VLC, for instance, works, particularly if I [enable X11 display](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=624017). But I need Mplayer for certain videos (MPEG transport streams that don't start on a nice boundary), and I believe DVBcut uses it too.

When I try to use Mplayer on any video, for instance a MPEG2 video, I get a window with no video, no audio, and the following errors:

```
libavformat version 56.40.101 (internal)
MPEG-PS file format detected.
VIDEO:  MPEG2  704x480  (aspect 2)  29.970 fps  9500.0 kbps (1187.5 kbyte/s)
Load subtitles in ./
Can't open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[fbdev2] Can't open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
VO: [v4l2] No such file or directory
vo_cvidix: No vidix driver name provided, probing available ones (-v option for details)!
[cyberblade] Error occurred during pci scan: Operation not permitted
[mach64] Error occurred during pci scan: Operation not permitted
[mga] Error occurred during pci scan: Operation not permitted
[mga] Error occurred during pci scan: Operation not permitted
[nvidia_vid] Error occurred during pci scan: Operation not permitted
[pm3] Error occurred during pci scan: Operation not permitted
[radeon] Error occurred during pci scan: Operation not permitted
[rage128] Error occurred during pci scan: Operation not permitted
[s3_vid] Error occurred during pci scan: Operation not permitted
[SiS] Error occurred during pci scan: Operation not permitted
[unichrome] Error occurred during pci scan: Operation not permitted

[VO_SUB_VIDIX] Couldn't find working VIDIX driver.
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 56.60.100 (internal)
Selected video codec: [ffmpeg2] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-2)
==========================================================================
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
[ac3 @ 0x55b6aab0b9e0]frame sync error
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 192.0 kbit/6.25% (ratio: 24000->384000)
Selected audio codec: [ffac3] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AC-3)
==========================================================================
[AO OSS] audio_setup: Can't open audio device /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
DVB card number must be between 1 and 4
AO: [null] 48000Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
[ac3 @ 0x55b6aab0b9e0]incomplete frame
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
VO: [null] 704x480 => 704x480 Planar YV12 
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [null] 704x480 => 704x528 Planar YV12 
A:   0.3 V:   0.3 A-V:  0.016 ct:  0.003   4/  4 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[VD_FFMPEG] DRI failure.
A:   0.5 V:   0.9 A-V: -0.443 ct: -0.035  22/ 22  8%  0%  0.2% 0 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[ac3 @ 0x55b6aab0b9e0]frame sync error
A:   1.9 V:   1.9 A-V:  0.006 ct:  0.027  51/ 51  8%  0%  0.8% 0 0
```

[Somebody suggested](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=764592) trying sudo for this kind of error.  So I tried sudo.

```
libavformat version 56.40.101 (internal)
MPEG-PS file format detected.
VIDEO:  MPEG2  704x480  (aspect 2)  29.970 fps  9500.0 kbps (1187.5 kbyte/s)
Load subtitles in ./
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 56.60.100 (internal)
Selected video codec: [ffmpeg2] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-2)
==========================================================================
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
[ac3 @ 0x55c88c19e9e0]frame sync error
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 192.0 kbit/6.25% (ratio: 24000->384000)
Selected audio codec: [ffac3] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AC-3)
==========================================================================
[AO OSS] audio_setup: Can't open audio device /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
DVB card number must be between 1 and 4
AO: [null] 48000Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
[ac3 @ 0x55c88c19e9e0]incomplete frame
Could not find matching colorspace - retrying with -vf scale...
Opening video filter: [scale]
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
[swscaler @ 0x55c88c1b2360]bicubic scaler, from yuv420p to bgra using MMXEXT
[swscaler @ 0x55c88c1b2360]using unscaled yuv420p -> bgra special converter
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x480 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [fbdev] 704x480 => 704x528 BGRA 
Can't put VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.

FATAL: Could not initialize video filters (-vf) or video output (-vo).


Exiting... (End of file)
```

An empty Mplayer window didn't even appear this time.

System info if you need it, from inxi -b:

```
System:    Host: Serial-Peacemaker Kernel: 4.4.0-24-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: Gigabyte product: N/A
           Mobo: Gigabyte model: Z170N-WIFI-CF v: x.x
           Bios: American Megatrends v: F4 date: 09/04/2015
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-6100 (-HT-MCP-) speed/max: 799/3700 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.3 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V driver: e1000e
           Card-2: Intel I211 Gigabit Network Connection driver: igb
           Card-3: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 5501.1GB (18.4% used)
Info:      Processes: 248 Uptime: 5 days Memory: 3598.4/32056.5MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.35
```

So, what am I missing?  Or is Mplayer on Intel HD 530 just not possible at this time?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for [a solution to the audio issue](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292408) finally provided a solution.  There were two mplayer binaries on my system!  /usr/local/bin/mplayer was the default.  But when I tried /usr/bin/mplayer, everything worked. (Except DVBCut audio.)

So, I got rid of /usr/local/bin/mplayer.  `sudo gzip /usr/local/bin/mplayer` just in case I ever need it again.